# Android Split data in two

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, spinner

I need to split a data into two, for example I am getting a data of users along with mobile number so data is like Arif||44444~Balin||33333~Cavin||55555~Den||66666~ So I this can be split like

```
//Splitting the values
String[] parts = stat.split("~");
final String part1 = parts[0];
final String part2 = parts[1];
```

But this will get data like Arif||44444, Balin||33333, Cavin||55555, Den||66666

I need to store the data including the name and phonenumber seperately, and I need to display the name in a spinner, so if user select the name from spinner I need to get its corresponding mobile number. I did code for selecting the name.. but for corresponding number I am not getting, if anyone knows please help.

```
ref = String.valueOf(refdetails.getString("ref", "not found"));

List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
//spinnerArray.add(ref);
spinnerArray = Arrays.asList(ref.split("~"));

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
  this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type 1: using regular Expression.

It split non-word character.

parts[i].split("[\W]{2}")

```
    String stat = "Arif||44444~Balin||33333~Cavin||55555~Den||66666~";
    String[] parts = stat.split("~");
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {         
        names.add(parts[i].split("[\\W]{2}")[0]);          
        numbers.add(parts[i].split("[\\W]{2}")[1]);
    }
```

Type 2: Using Substring

```
    String stat = "Arif||44444~Balin||33333~Cavin||55555~Den||66666~";
    String[] parts = stat.split("~");
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {         
        int found = parts[i].indexOf("||");
        names.add(parts[i].substring(0,found));         

        numbers.add(parts[i].substring(found+2,parts[i].length()));

    }


 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()   {
   @Override
   public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int posion, long id) {

     //here you can get the position (local argument position) of corresponding numbers to the names         

      String name = names.get(position); 
      String number = number.get(position);
   }
  @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  } 
});
```

Comment: Arun how i will get the corresponding numbers for the names..if user select a particular name

Comment: you can get using position. i.e  position = names.indexOf("Arif"); numbers.get(position)

Comment: I add the spinner item selected listener

Comment: @Jocheved you got result?

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] parts = stat.split("~");
final String part1 = parts[0];
final String part2 = parts[1];
```

This will split the string into an array `{ "Arif||44444", "Balin||33333", "Cavin||55555", "Den||66666" }`

To get the name and the number of each, you can do some more splitting:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    names.append(parts[i].split("||")[0]);  
    numbers.append(parts[i].split("||")[1]);    
}
```

you will now have 2 lists, `{ "Arif", "Balin", "Cavin", "Den" }` and `{ "44444", "33333", "55555", "66666" }` respectively.

Comment: How I will take the corresponding number when user selects a name

Comment: @Jocheved I suggest you make a `Person` or similar class that holds the name and number of each. Then you can create new Persons in this for loop and refer to them after. If the data is together in a container (a class in this case) it's easier to match the data

Answer (score 0):

first **Prepare value for spinner** and add all data to an hashmap

```
String[] parts = stat.split("~");
String[] sArray = new String[parts.length];
HashMap<String,String> sMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
int i=0;
for (String s : parts)
{
   sMap.put(s.split("|")[0],s.split("|")[1]);
   sArray[i] = s.split("|")[0];
   i++;
}
```

Next set the **values for spinner**, like you do on your code.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sArray);

         // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
         // Apply the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then if you want to **get value of spinner** access your hashmap

```
String name = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
String id = sMap.get(name);
```